# Using level and connect by clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Need a simplified alternative for the below query.

```
select trim(lpad(' *',level*2,'* ')) from dual connect by level < 5;
```

Output:

```
*
*  *
* *  *
* * *  *
```

Comment: Can you tell us please why?

Comment: Do you want whitespaces sam as your question? I assume you did not post proper pattern.

Comment: The OP's query generates the white-space in the output. There will be 1 space character between stars except for the last gap where there will be two spaces; this is an artefact of them using `' *'` for the initial string and `'* '` for the padding string.

Comment: This query is already really simple, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

That query is about as simple as you are going to get.

If you want to use a recursive sub-query factoring clause then you can do this:

```sql
WITH data ( value, lvl ) AS (
  SELECT CAST(' *' AS VARCHAR2(8)), 1 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
  SELECT '* ' || value, lvl + 1
  FROM   data
  WHERE  lvl + 1< 5
)
SELECT TRIM(value)
FROM   data;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select rpad('*',level*2,' *') from dual connect by level < 5;
```

I am not capable of simplifying it more than that.

Comment: The two are not the same as the white-space in the output is different from the OP's question.

Comment: I guess he needs a proper pattern